# When should I run daily ETL jobs for Firebase Analytics data exported to BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, etl, firebase-analytics

We use Firebase Analytics to collect events from our apps. We have enabled events export to BigQuery. Every day we run some ETL jobs to create more friendly analytics tables in BigQuery (e.g. sessions, purchases).

The question is when should we run these ETL jobs?

We know that Firebase Analytics creates in BigQuery 'events_intraday_' table which is changed to 'events_' after some hours after midnight. We also understand that some events might be reported later if client is not connected with the internet, but this is not the problem.

Our theory is that 'events_intraday_' table is some kind of temporary table and we should run ETL jobs when it changes to 'events_'. Unfortunately we could not find any documentation about it. Is this good solution?

Answer (score 2):

From [Announcing Realtime Exporting of your Analytics Data into BigQuery](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/real-time-exporting-of-analytics-data-into-bigquery.html):

> At the end of the day [1], this data will be moved into its permanent appevents_ home, and the old intraday table will be automatically cleaned up for you.

With:

> [1] This is determined by looking at the developer's time zone.

So it looks like the daily table is created at midnight  for *your* timezone.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the true. We usually observe that daily table is created around 6 AM UTC+0 (but it can happen also around 10 AM).
I'm glad that you reminded me about Firebase Blog. I've found there article which anwers my question.

Comment: I forgot to mention that our timezone is UTC+1/+2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) I've found article on Firebase Blog
[How Long Does it Take for My Firebase Analytics Data to Show Up?](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html), which says that analytics data exported to BigQuery can be delayed up to little more than 1 hour. So based on this information ETL jobs should be runned about, lets say 2 AM UTC+0 and query should just UNION ALL events with events_intraday table.

So if today is 2019-04-02 and I want to query data from last month, the query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM `<PROJECT_ID>.analytics_<ANALYTICS_ID>.events_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190301' AND '20190401'
)
UNION ALL 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM `<PROJECT_ID>.analytics_<ANALYTICS_ID>.events_intraday_*` 
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20190401'
)
```