# When is an events_intraday table migrated to the events_ dataset on BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

After the previous day intraday table is finalised in the events_intraday dataset, is there a particular time of day when it is migrated to the events_ dataset or does it happen randomly?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55457710/9928809) fit your question?

Comment: Hi @mk_sta, thanks for the comment. The link you sent says that the events_intraday table is changed to the events_ dataset approximately 1-2 hours after midnight (according to my timezone). My timezone is UTC+5:30 and yet I've noticed that the table shifts at around 11 am everyday, sometimes 12 pm.

Comment: Hi, @RitwikSrivastava, is there some data in your "events_intraday" table? I'm trying to get some data from this table, but it is always empty. But my event table get new data every day.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html) Firebase article?

Comment: @TúlioCalazans yes there is data in the intraday table. it gets updated every 5 mins or so. i think you should contact bigquery support once since this is unlikely that the intraday table would be empty yet the events table would have data