# Events table is created too late in BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am exporting my app's events from Firebase to BigQuery on a regular basis. This system creates an 'events_intraday_YYYYMMDD' table for the current day we are in, and for the previous days, the data is stored in 'events_YYYYMMDD' tables, one for every day. When the day ends, the events_intraday table is converted to an events table, and a new intraday table is created for the new day. This normally happens around early in the morning.

Recently, this process started to take too long. The new intraday tables are created when they should've been, but the older ones are not converted to events tables. For example, today (15 Apr 2021) I still have the events table for the 14th as an intraday table, which should've been saved as an events table  much earlier. In the last couple of days, intraday tables are kept as long as 2-3 days.

I've looked at every documentation in Firebase, Google Analytics, and BigQuery. But could not find a solution to this, nor how to edit the settings for this if there is any. Firebase says that I should check the 'event export settings' in Google Analytics, but there is no such option there.

Anyone else ever experienced the same problem?

Comment: maybe you shall submit this as a bug or support ticket to Google BigQuery / firesbase team

Comment: check the timezone of your GA property. Maybe someone changed it? also there is no SLA for the data freshness in BQ, the new GA will have it.

Comment: @AlienDeg thanks for the answer. I've checked my project's timezone and it is correct. The timezone affects when the intraday table is created and starts recording events. It starts recording everyday at 00.00 at the project's timezone, but it takes very long to save it as an events table even though it's not updated anymore in the new day.

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454574/when-should-i-run-daily-etl-jobs-for-firebase-analytics-data-exported-to-bigquer which does not have answer either :(

Comment: @OnurKorkmaz were you able to find a solution for this behavior ?